# Why trying to put a vertical heading, should we rotate it 90 degrees or 270 degrees?

Tags: css, user-interface

I am trying to place a vertical heading beside the content. Which one should be the "correct" way to place the heading?

Is that a convention about this?

a) rotate 90 degrees:

[image]

b) rotate 270 degrees:

[image]

Comment: I would argue the first is better as english reads from top left to right

Comment: I think it's up to you really. I would say reading down is easier than reading up personally (first one). My eyes instinctively go to the top left of a piece of text because I expect it to start there. I don't really want to go tracing down to find where something I want to read starts if you get what I mean. </ramble>

Comment: Both are a strain to read really. But the first one is more readable, since it's the convention on books, dvds etc.

Comment: This question is either too broad,**opinion based** or invites discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Perhaps UX.StackExchange?

Comment: Looking at existing programs, I think the second is more prevalent. [Example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zBWwC.png).

Comment: This question has been asked and answered on UX SE: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/14745/is-clockwise-or-counter-clockwise-rotated-text-easier-to-read